# Why is my Quick Sort wrong in only 1 spot in the array?

Tags: c++, quicksort

Im implementing quicksort for an assignment, and I have it complete, but the sorted array is wrong in only 1 spot. Heres the output.

```
Array before QuickSort: 5 99 32 4 1 12 15 8 13 55
Array after QuickSort: 1 5 4 8 12 13 15 32 55 99
```

It sorts the array correctly for everything **except the 5 and the 4**.  Iv played with the debugger for hours and cant figure out why this is happening, can anyone please help? Iv posted my QuickSort code below.

```
int main()
{
int quickArray[SIZE] = { 5 ,99, 32, 4, 1, 12, 15 , 8, 13, 55};
int arrStartIndex = 0;
int arrEndIndex =9;

//Code to print array at start
QuickSort(quickArray,arrStartIndex,arrEndIndex);
//Code to print array after sort

return 0
}
```

.........................................................................................

```
void QuickSort(int ar2[],int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
//Begin QuickSort
int Q;
if( startIndex < endIndex )
{
    Q =  Partition(ar2,startIndex,endIndex);
    QuickSort(ar2,startIndex,Q-1);
    QuickSort(ar2,Q+1,endIndex);
}
//End QuickSort
}
```

..............................................................................................

```
int Partition(int ar2[],int P, int R)
{
int x = ar2[R];
int i = P-1;
int temp;

for(int j = P; j <= R-1; j++)
{
    if( ar2[j] < x  )
    {
        i = i +1;
        temp = ar2[i];
        ar2[i] = ar2[j];
        ar2[j] = temp;
    }

    temp = ar2[R];
    ar2[R] = ar2[i+1];
    ar2[i+1] = temp;
}

return (i+1);
}
```

Comment: Try with fewer inputs.

Comment: The first thing I'd look at is that swap you are doing every time around the loop without doing any ordering test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this code, which if I understand correctly moves the pivot to its final position should be outside the for loop

```
temp = ar2[R];
ar2[R] = ar2[i+1];
ar2[i+1] = temp;
```

Comment: In my notes, it looks like I wrote this inside the for loop, when It really goes outside it, my mistake XD  Thank you